# library override on linked collection resets transform

Tags: transforms, library-overrides, library

When I add a library override to a linked collection that has been transformed in scene... The collection moves back to it's original place in the scene. I need it to stay where it is.
Is this expected behaviour? Is there a way to library override - keep transformation?

eg, two scenes showing the same product from the same angle. One scene has a different coloured part than the other. Library override, change material, render.

edit: I'm still struggling with this a month later. Does anyone have any experience with this? An alternative workflow, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

One work around I found was to go to *Object > Apply > Make Instances Real*.

This might break your workflow, since it is technically just making the linked asset an appended object now, but it helped me out with a large scene that I built from linked assets that I transformed and needed to edit later without loosing those transforms.

I hope this helps you, or if you figured out any other solution that allows library overrides without ruining transforms, let me know - or even let me know if there is a bug report that you want me to tag on to.